# write nodejs web application like php

Tags: php, node.js

How can I write `nodejs` (with and without express framework) app that do such think in `php`:

```
<doctype hyml>
<html>
<body>
<h1> <?php echo "Hi"; ?> </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

with or without express.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to setup your node.js project to use a template engine like jade.

**app.js**

By doing that you need to install jade with npm and require the dependency into your project.

```
var express = require('express');
var jade = require('jade');
var app = express();
```

Then you have to tell express.js to use the jade template engine.

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Then you use the render function to render the index.jade with the second param as an object.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        msg: 'Hi'
    });
}
```

**views/index.jade**

The #{msg} placeholder will then be compiled into 'Hi'.

```
html
    body
        h1 #{msg}
```